# How can I query "select if exist" else "select another" procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is what I am trying to do, create a new CTE and select everything from currentWindow if 
any data exists in it, if not the CTE should contains everything from PastWindows.

```
    currentWindow as  (
select * from Window oew
where oew.StartDate <= GETDATE() and oew.EndDate >= GETDATE()
)
    , PastWindows as 
(
        select * from Window oew
        where oew.StartDate between DATEADD(YYYY, -1, GetDate()) AND GETDATE()
        OR oew.EndDate between DATEADD(YYYY, -1, GetDate()) AND GETDATE()
)
```

Something like this

```
FinalOEWindoToUse as
```

(

)

I understand that this can be done using a case statement for a single column, but in this case I want all the columns from table A if data exists and all data from table B if it exists there

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Edited the post, sql server.

Comment: So you want the data from both of these queries?

Comment: Yeah if select count(*) from currentWindow  then select * from currentWindow ELSE select * from PastWindows

Comment: @I486 do you think your answer can be further made in a CTE. This is a long query of multiple part cascaded Common table expression style query

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM Window oew WHERE oew.StartDate <= GETDATE() and oew.EndDate >= GETDATE())
    SELECT * FROM Window oew WHERE oew.StartDate <= GETDATE() and oew.EndDate >= GETDATE()
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM Window oew WHERE oew.StartDate BETWEEN DATEADD(YYYY, -1, GetDate()) AND GETDATE() OR oew.EndDate between DATEADD(YYYY, -1, GetDate()) AND GETDATE()
```